# How do I only allow require_once things depending on which page 'required' it?

Tags: php

I just had an idea to make things a little cleaner and less cluttered. And I'm wondering if it's at all possible to determine *which* page is requesting access to another PHP file?

Index.php:

```
<?php
    require_once('RequiredThing.php');
    // ...
?>
```

RequiredThing.php:

```
<?php
    if(INDEX-PAGE REQUESTED THIS)
    {
        // Do stuff.
    }
    else if(ABOUT-PAGE REQUESTED THIS)
    {
        // Do diffrent stuff.
    }
?>
```

I hope this is making sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
if(basename(__FILE__, '.php') === "index")
{
    // Do stuff.
}
else if(basename(__FILE__, '.php') === "about")
{
    // Do diffrent stuff.
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

Just a little trick to do this . i hope this will help . before require just define $page var.

about.php

```
  <?php
    $page = 'about';
    require 'RequiredThing.php';
    ?>
```

Index.php

```
   <?php
     $page = 'index';
    require 'RequiredThing.php';
```

RequiredThing.php

```
if($page == 'about'){
    // Do stuff. 
}elseif($page == 'index'){
    // Do diffrent stuff
}
```

?>